# How to POST and GET that data from a web API. (Retrofit/Kotlin/Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new to web APIs and retrofit. I'm interacting with [TheCatApi](https://docs.thecatapi.com/) and having trouble fetching data that I posted. The API has a list of images and a feature to choose several as favorites with POST requests and retrieve a list of favorites.

My main issue probably has to do with the data class (I have 2):

-For the Image GET request

```
data class CatPhoto (
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: String,
    @Json(name = "url")
    val imgSrcUrl: String,
    @Json(name = "breeds")
    val breeds: List<Any>,
    @Json(name = "width")
    val width: Int,
    @Json(name = "height")
    val height: Int
)

@GET("$API_V/favourites?limit=100")
suspend fun getMyFavorites(
    @Query("sub_id") subId: String
): List<CatPhoto>
```

-To make an image a favorite using a POST request

```
data class FavouriteImage (
    val image_id: String,
    val sub_id: String,
)

@POST("$API_V/favourites?limit=100")
suspend fun addFavorite(
   @Body favouriteImage: FavouriteImage
)
```

This is the error after I POST a favourite and try to retrieve a list of posted favourites:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Required value 'imgSrcUrl' (JSON name 'url') missing at $[.1]

It looks like it's expecting `imgSrcUrl` attribute on the `FavouriteImage` data class, which makes me think I shouldn't even have the `FavouriteImage` class. But then how do I make the post request that requires `image_id` and `sub_id` in the body?

Here's how I set up the database in the API service file:

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
object CatsApi {
    val catsApiService : CatsApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(CatsApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

[backend of the github project](https://github.com/edcres/rate-cats/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/ratecats/data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: As [@extremeoats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8917070/extremeoats) wrote in comments, the api doesn't support passing urls an image indentifier and you have to save its id also for the operations like making favorite etc.

**Old answer**

Could you please add some code of how a request is made?
It's a local error of Moshi trying to parse the **response** and not seing the required field (maybe got an error from server - the data structure of an error would be different from a normal response)

I've built a sample app to test this and get a proper response when marking the image as a fav. You are right to use the structure with an image_id and sub_id. Here are some code parts if it helps

1. Set up the Retrofit (interceptor for debug only, so you can see what exactly you sent and got back)

```
        private val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ServerApi.BASE_URL)
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build()
            )
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        private val api = retrofit.create(ServerApi::class.java)
```

1.1. A dependency for the logging interceptor and OkHttp

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
```

2. Api interface

   ```
    interface ServerApi {
        companion object {
            const val API_KEY: String = **PASTE YOUR API KEY HERE**
            const val AUTH_HEADER = "x-api-key"
            const val BASE_URL = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/"
        }

        @GET("images/search")
        fun getImages(@Header(AUTH_HEADER) authHeader: String = API_KEY, @Query("limit") limit: Int = 5): Call<List<ImagesItem>>

        @POST("favourites")
        fun postFavourite(@Header(AUTH_HEADER) authHeader: String = API_KEY, @Body payload: PostFavouritePayload): Call<String>
    }

    private var listMyData = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ImagesItem::class.java)
    private val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<ImagesItem>> = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(listMyData)
   ```
3. Use the api

   ```
    api.getImages().enqueue(object : Callback<List<ImagesItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ImagesItem>>, response: Response<List<ImagesItem>>) {
                val images = response.body() ?: return
                api.postFavourite(payload = PostFavouritePayload(images[0].id, **PASTE ANY STRING HERE AS USER ID**))
                    .enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) =
                            Log.d("TestCatApi", "SUCCESS posting a fav: ${response.body()}")
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable)  =
                            t.printStackTrace()
                    })
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ImagesItem>>, t: Throwable) =
                t.printStackTrace()
        })
   ```

Side notes:

1. For such example APIs I find very useful a plugin "Json to Kotlin class". Alt+K, then you can paste the String response from a Server or in example, and you have a decent starting point for the data classes (not affiliated with them)
2. Just in case: you can pass a baseUrl to the Retrofit builder like that

   ```
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ServerApi.BASE_URL)...
   ```

Then you put in @Get, @Post etc. only the part after the "/" of a base url: "images/search"

Comment: I set up my API service in a simpler way, so I need to learn some of the code you wrote. I didn't understand what you're asking me to send but here's a link to the backend of my project and I'll update my question. https://github.com/edcres/rate-cats/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/ratecats/data

Comment: Sorry for the late response, also could you go into more detail about this local error of Moshi, maybe this will fix my problem.

Comment: Could you please try with the logging interceptor and look into the response you get? This will help for sure. I've edited the answer with the corresponding dependency

Comment: The slashes seem to work fine, I've looked into it and I believe it's added automatically withe the request type annotation (ie. GET/POST). I'll take some time implementing your suggestions and reply here.

Comment: It turns out I was trying to get an API response with the URL of the image but it looks like the API doesn't offer that. My solution was to save the image id with the URL in a local database so if you want to write that I'll mark yours as the answer.